# In Swift and SpriteKit - how to enable particles emitter and fade it out withing a 1 second?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, particle-system

I have an app which has moving sprites. Once I swipe\touch a sprite - it disappears. What I also made is that at the location where that sprite disappears I spawn a Smoke particles emitter. But it keeps "running" while I want it to "fade out"..disperse.. So for now the way it works for me is that I spawn is with a birthrate = 100 and once a new sprite added to the screen (added every half a second) I change it's birthrate to 0.

It does give an effect...sort of what i want, but it's desynced and not ideal.

Can I somehow set the emitter at location and from that moment make it "fade away" withing a given time? for example reduce it's birthrate from 100 to 0 within 1 sec, but async!

The code is like this:

GameScene.swift

```
 class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
   var spriteSmoke = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "GoneSpriteSmoke")

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     spriteSmoke.position = CGPointMake(-100, -100)
     self.addChild(spriteSmoke)
     spriteSmoke.targetNode = self
 }

   override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    //i have a sprite name check implemented to remove correct sprites.
    if let theName = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
        if theName == task.lowercaseString {
            //sprite has to be removed
            //spawn smoke on it's place
            spriteSmoke.particleBirthRate = 200
            spriteSmoke.position = location
            self.removeChildrenInArray([self.nodeAtPoint(location)])


        }
    }

}

  func addFood() {
   //this func is called from another routine, every .5 sec.
   //SETTING UP THE SPRITE HERE
   //position, scale and so on...

   //adding new sprite to the scene
   addChild(food)

   //setting the existing SMOKE emmiter to the 0 BR to simulate it's fading away. 
   //Since this func is called each 0.5 sec, it works OK-iiissshhhhh if in those 0.5 sec any smoke emitter was places.
   spriteSmoke.particleBirthRate = 0


  }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you good..Do you just want to fade an emitter away by fading it's alpha property, or something else? I don't think this is the case, but if it is, you can run an SKAction fadeAlphaTo: on it. Also there is particleAlphaSequence. The sequence is used to specify the alpha value of a particle over its lifetime. And if this doesn't suits you , maybe you could try to set the number of particles to emit : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/numParticlesToEmit

Comment: @Whirlwind `numParticlesToEmit` is what can really work for me. But when does it reset? do i need to remove the particle node and add again for it to reset or can i reset it somehow else?

Comment: To reset it, you can use resetSimulation function... I guess you want to spawn smoke particles at multiple places at the time ? To do that, you can't use single emitter node, obviously, because node can only be at one place at the time. So you have to use copy of that emitter (cached one) and then you should calculate when to remove those copies from parent. Because even if emitter isn't visible, it is still there (check node count of its parent to see this). Then you have to calculate when to remove node. Search SO, I think there are few posts about this...Hope this lead you somewhere...